# Randomly picking out of an array in PHP

Tags: php, random

I have an array that has values like 1, 5, 6, 9, 11, 45, 56, etc. What I'm trying to do is to randomly one value, perhaps 6. Then I want to pick a random value excluding 6 (so no doubles). Then a random value excluding the last two, all from inside an array. Any help? I'm trying to do this without `while` loops but if they are necessary then so be it.

Comment: what's wrong with while loops?

Comment: You could always use recursion ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion ), but essentialy the end result is the same, a loop.

Comment: what do you need to get in the end? the same array with randomized order of the elements?

Comment: Randomly what one value? This is a family site...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
# pick a random key in your array
$rand_key = array_rand($your_array);

# extract the corresponding value
$rand_value = $your_array[$rand_key];

# remove the key-value pair from the array
unset($your_array[$rand_key]);
```

See: [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

Answer (score 7):

Shuffle the array first and then use it as a stack:

```
$a = array(1, 5, 6, 9, 11, 45, 56);
shuffle($a);

// now you can have your picks:
$pick = array_pop($a);
$pick = array_pop($a);
$pick = array_pop($a);
$pick = array_pop($a);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array and get the first/last x value