# How to randomly take examples from arrays, shuffle them and place them into a new array to be formatted as a list

Tags: php, arrays, list, for-loop

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242012/how-do-you-store-random-parts-of-an-array-within-an-array-and-then-print-as-a-li) I didn't realize that I wouldn't be able to add in the rest of the changes myself, so here is what I'm working with. User webfix helped me get this:

```
$mars = array ('How big is Mars?', 'How many moons does Mars have?', 'How far away is Mars?', 'What is the highest point on Mars?');
$jupiter = array ('How big is Jupiter?', 'How many moons does Jupiter have?', 'How far away is Jupiter?', 'What is the highest point on Jupiter?');
$earth = array ('How big is Earth?', 'How many moons does Earth have?', 'How far away is Earth?', 'What is the highest point on Earth?');
$sun = array ('How big is the Sun?', 'How many moons does the Sun have?', 'How far away is the Sun?', 'What is the highest point on the Sun?');

$all = array($mars, $jupiter, $earth, $sun);

function createList($a)
{
echo "<ul>";    
foreach ($a as $array) 
    {
    $questions = count($array);
    $idquestion = rand(0, $questions-1);
    echo "<li>" . $array[$idquestion]  . "</li>";
    }
echo "</ul>";
}

createList($all);
```

I now want to add to this a randomization of the order of questions as well as a maximum of three (or any number to be changed later) questions spit out.

It currently will choose one of each question ($mars, $jupiter, $earth, $sun) and then make it into a list in that order. I want the order to be randomized and for only three of them to be chosen.

I tried to use "shuffle ($all)", but that didn't work and maybe we could use something like the "for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++)" to make it stop after picking three? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have not added or changed *anything* since the answer to your last question. If you did do something, please let us know what you've tried (including research!).

Comment: I've looked extensively on the internet and on stackoverflow for randomization of an array. And the examples don't seem to work with this function. I tried adding shuffle ($all) into the program, but that was ignored by the server and I don't know why. I tried to add in a for loop, but as a novice  programer, I don't really understand how everything works and ever after reading up on these things, I understand, but for some reason can't get them to work with the code that I want. All the little bits makes sense to me, but I don't know how to fit them all together.

Comment: Do you still want one question from each sub-array, or are two Mars questions OK?

Comment: I want a max of one from each, but only three in total. (so one randomly doesn't get chosen)

Comment: @Alex: After 20 seconds of searching this site, I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145999/randomly-picking-out-of-an-array-in-php. It shows how to select something randomly and then remove that option (so it doesn't get selected again). Using that, you should be able to build what you're asking.

Comment: Where did you put `shuffle($all)`? I put it right after `$all = array(...);`, it worked fine.

Comment: I did too, but for some reason when I was doing it before the program seemed to skip the shuffle. Your answer Barmar works, thanks. And Tomas, I understand how you could be annoyed, but I actually did try a lot of things, but I guess I placed things in the wrong location and was slightly off on a few things which made it not work in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shuffle($all)` should work (it works for me), I don't know why it isn't for you. To pick three, do:

```
$mars = array ('How big is Mars?', 'How many moons does Mars have?', 'How far away is Mars?', 'What is the highest point on Mars?');
$jupiter = array ('How big is Jupiter?', 'How many moons does Jupiter have?', 'How far away is Jupiter?', 'What is the highest point on Jupiter?');
$earth = array ('How big is Earth?', 'How many moons does Earth have?', 'How far away is Earth?', 'What is the highest point on Earth?');
$sun = array ('How big is the Sun?', 'How many moons does the Sun have?', 'How far away is the Sun?', 'What is the highest point on the Sun?');

$all = array($mars, $jupiter, $earth, $sun);
shuffle($all);

function createList($a)
{
  echo "<ul>"; 
  $count = 1;

  foreach ($a as $array) 
    {
      $questions = count($array);
      $idquestion = rand(0, $questions-1);
      echo "<li>" . $array[$idquestion]  . "</li>";
      if ($count++ >= 3) {
        break;
      }
    }
  echo "</ul>";
}

createList($all);
```

`break` terminates a loop early.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/GT1kRM)

Comment: Thanks, but that chooses only the first three. It isn't random

Comment: I ran it, I'm getting random questions. I guess I'll have to post to IDEone.com to prove it, give me a sec.